# can't get onbeforeunload working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I've looked at similar questions on this website, but I haven't seen why this doesn't work for me.

I have the latest version of chrome installed. 
I can't seem to get the following code to work in chrome, it works in firefox though.

```
Hello World!

<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        alert("brohan");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is actually running, the problem is that Chrome does not allow alerts in onbeforeunload, while Firefox does.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, your script is supposed to look like this:

```
<script>
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "brohan";
  };
</script>
```

If you want to inform Firefox 4+ users too of *why* you are asking them (where your hopefully helpful message is [intentionally disabled](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292)), you can adopt this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ecmanaut/hQ3AQ/

Answer (score 0):

It may be late but I want to add some update here:

1. Custom message in `window.onbeforeunload` is stilled intentionally disabled by Firefox (I am using version 35.0). :(
2. The workaround raised by @ecmanaut is not working now -- it seems Firefox has disabled `window.alert` within the onbeforeunload handler. Described in [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=969787#c10)

And I've tried it myself in Firefox 35.0 in Mac OS X:

```
var isFirefox = /Firefox[\/\s](\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent) && new Number(RegExp.$1) > 4;
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  if (isFirefox) {
    window.alert('You are in firefox. Leaving this page you may lose some data.');
    return '...';
  }
  else {
    return 'Leaving this page you may lose some data.';
  }
 }
```

When refreshing/clicking external links, this snippet won't fire the `alert` function, neither the default alert box from browser. It just leave the page.

Hope this message helps.